# If $x+yi$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$, then $N(x+yi)$ is a prime number in $\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am seeking a proof of: If $x+yi$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ and one have $x\ne 0,y\ne0$, then $N(x+yi)$ is a prime. where $N: x+yi \to x^2 + y^2$

Now firstly note that $x\ne 0,y\ne0$ is really important because otherwise 3 in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ already serves as a counterexample to this argument. Assume $x^2+y^2$ is not a prime, then it can be uniquely factorized into $p_1 p_2 ... p_n$.

From this point on I tried several approaches.

1. trying to explicitly construct $(a+bi)(c+di) = (x+yi)$. This doesn't seem to work.
2. (making use of $\mathbb{Z}[i]$ being UFD). If $\pi$ is irreducible, $\pi = x+yi$ is a prime element, then let ($\pi$) be the prime ideal $\pi$ generated. Moreover $(\pi) \cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$. As prime ideals in $\mathbb{Z}$ are exactly $p\mathbb{Z}$ for $p$ prime in $\mathbb{Z}$, and $ p \in (\pi)$ and one have $\pi \gamma = p.$ Therefore $N(\pi)N(\gamma) = N(p) = p^2$. If somehow $N(\pi)$ is not a prime, we reach a contradiction. Note that since $y \ne 0$,   $\pi \ne p$.

My question: is the above statement correct, or, in some ways "minimal"? Particularly I am having this doubt in mind because we can always use the established results (which classify irreducibile elements in $\mathbb{Z}[i]$) and derive the same conclusion.

*I am a noob in abstract algebra and commutative algebra so any answer/remarks would be of extreme help. Thanks!

**I note that none of people left any remarks on this question so far. If it is trivial, boring or wrong, please enlighten me and I shall delete the post.

Comment: Try here https://brilliant.org/wiki/gaussian-integers/#:~:text=A%20Gaussian%20integer%20is%20called%20prime%20if%20it,example%2C%205%3D%20%282%2Bi%29%20%282-i%29%205%20%3D%20%282%2Bi%29%282%E2%88%92i%29

Comment: Note that a gaussian integer irreducible iff it's a gaussian prime.